# How to install SSL certificate on Redis server over port 6379 OR how to call same on http node server

Tags: node.js, redis

We have developed application in CodeIgniter (port 443) and Node JS (port 8080) and using Redis (port 6379) in node js.

and SSL certificate are installed in port 443 and 8080 but we are trying to connect redis server over https then it is not working but it is working fine over http.

Please guide.

Comment: Does this help : https://redis.io/topics/encryption ?